# First Cut Sequence Diagram response

Tags: diagram, sequence-diagram

Here is an image of my first cut sequence diagram:

[image]

My question is this: the retrieveStockInfo(stkID,stkInfo) method gets the data that is wanted to be shown to the customer. At the moment, I have a response to the activation 'box'. Is this correct? Do I need to return anything else to the actual Customer?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to return the information to the customer otherwise they will never know what happened!

You might also want to put in error handling sequences. These are often forgotten about in sequence diagrams.